# How to make an exception in select count() query in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to check my database if any of the text in my textbox and combobox are in it by my code, it's like I am trying to prevent 2 presidents in one partylist in terms of election, and it works fine, but when I make an exception for Representatives my code fails, is there any other way to do that?

this is my code:

```
Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    conn.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Candidate where cparty='" & Textbox1.Text & "' and cpos='" & ComboBox1.SelectedText & "' AND cpos<>'Representative (Grade 7)'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Load(dr)

    If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Position already exist in current Partylist")
    Else
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE candidate SET cpos='" & ComboBox1.Text & "', cparty='" & TextBox1.Text & "', candidacy='Filed' WHERE idn='" & cd & "'"

        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = sConnection
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("Record Updated")
        Dispose()
        Form17.Hide()
        Form5.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

when I use this query `"select count(*) from Candidate where cparty='" & TextBox1.SelectedText & "' and cpos='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"` it works fine, but if I add this one `AND cpos<>'Representative (Grade 7)'"` it doesn't work right. I know my `dr` still counts that, but I really have no idea what to do. help? :)

`candidate` table:

[image]

Comment: is their any error producing?

Comment: It gets really tedious saying this but learn to use parameterised queries. see [this](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29)

Comment: @NeethuSoman no sir, msgbox just keeps appearing.

Comment: have you tried ...AND NOT LIKE 'Representative (Grade 7)'...

Comment: @Markus it doesnt work.

Comment: can you show us the candidate table...some values?

Comment: this is almost certainly not what you want to do: `cparty='" & TextBox1.SelectedText & "' `.  Using SQL Parameters as you've been shown will simplify your code and make some error unlikely and ones like this more noticable.  You probably want `TextBox1.SelectedText`

Comment: My mistake, there done editing but still not working right.

Comment: `ComboBox1.SelectedTextTextbox1.Text` is nonsense too.  please paste the actual code

Comment: Oops sorry, that's my actual code now.

Comment: set a breakpoint and look at the sql which results for `cmd.CommandText`.  it still is not correct.  you have several other data conversions going on as well.  For instance since cid and idn are numeric, you should not be escaping them with ticks.  Using parameters would prevent this

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you what and definitely not the right way to do it:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Candidate where cparty='" & 
     TextBox1.SelectedText & "' and cpos='" & ComboBox1.Text  
     & "' AND cpos<>'Representative (Grade 7)'"
```

nor is Edit 3 correct:

```
"select count(*) from Candidate where cparty='" & 
  ComboBox1.SelectedText & "' and cpos='" & Textbox1.Text 
  & "' AND cpos<>'Representative (Grade 7)'"
```

The correct thing to do is to use parameters:

```
Dim sql As String ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Candidate WHERE cparty= @p1 AND " _
     & " cops = @p2 AND cpos <> @p3"
```

The `@pX` things are simply placeholders which you will provide the actual values for in a moment.  Most DB data objects support *named parameters* so that you can use `@party` or `@MeaningfulName`. OleDB (Access) treats these as positional placeholders only though.

Then after you build the command object you simply supply the values for the parameters:

```
' init cmd object with SQL and connection
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", ComboBox1.Text)  ' not .SelectedText
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", strExclude)
```

where `strExclude` would be whatever you want to exclude. Obviously using named parameters (*and* named controls) makes it even more readable and clearer which value to provide for each:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@party", tbParty.Text)
```

You also do not need to load a datatable to get the value, just use the reader:

```
     Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
         If rdr.HasRows Then
             rdr.Read()
             nCount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Item(0))
         End If
     End Using
```

Your UPDATE SQL appears to convert numerics to text: `WHERE idn='" & cd & "'"` adding the ticks passes text to the database and it appears these are actually numerics.  Parameters prevents this:

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE candidate SET cpos= @p1, cparty=@p2, " _
        & "candidacy='Filed' WHERE idn=@p3"
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con),

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ComboBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cd)
```

As noted in comments, the UPDATE will probably never run because your COUNT query will always return a row.  Finally, note that `Using/End Using` blocks disposes of objects which ought be disposed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i really don't know how to put it up together i'm just new to parameters, is it like this? http://jpst.it/tNSP

Comment: pretty much - hard to tell without indenting (strExclude is not set either),  but there is a flaw in your logic even in the OP.  Your COUNT query will *always* return 1 row.  It is just that sometimes the value you read back will be Zero.  So you should `IF` on that value rather than `Rows.Count`.  I dont think your UPDATE block can ever execute as is.  Should also check that the right controls are being mapped to the placeholders - the generic names are not that useful/clear to outsiders like us.

Comment: thanks, i learned a lot from this, but i really can't apply this answer i don't know how to put them and to declare new variables.

Comment: what new vars do you need?  once you have params, you can safely pass the UI controls to them. `strExclude` was used as an example since you might well want to vary that query by position (Pres, VP, Rep...etc). just use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", "Representative (Grade 7)")` for starters I guess

Comment: by that i mean the `strExclude`(i see so, that was it) and `nCount`.

Comment: you can create whatever you need just like you did at the top of the procedure for the SQL objects: `Dim nCount As Integer` ... `Dim strExclude As String = "Representative (Grade 7)"`.  In case it is not clear, the reason everyone mentions params is that concatenating SQL as you were with embedded UI control text, a user can type stuff into a textbox which will DESTROY your database.  See: http://xkcd.com/327/